# Converter string em JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Tenho o seguinte *objeto*:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Gostaria de convertê-la em JSON para recuperar no php para realizar um laço for:

```
{"id":"1"}
{"id":"2"}
{"id":"3"}
{"id":"4"}
{"id":"5"}
{"id":"6"}
```

Eu pego esse valor de [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect).

Segue exemplo:

```
<select id="category" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Aventura</option>
    <option value="2">Comedia</option>
    <option value="3">Ficção</option>
    <option value="4">Drama</option>
    <option value="5">Novela</option>
    <option value="6">Category</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>    
    $('#category').click(function() {    
        alert($('#category').val());    
    })
</script>
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/w7aakdbb/54/

Comment: o JSON que você deu como exemplo é invalido, que tipo de estrutura você está precisando receber no servidor?

Comment: Um JSON objeto não pode ter chaves repetidas, não da pra saber se você quer criar um array de ids, um array de objetos ou só um objeto.

Comment: alterei. verifiquem por favor se está correto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o exemplo que você indicou no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/w7aakdbb/54/), o valor que você obtém do `select` já é um *array*, portanto a [solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204150/5878) da Aline deve funcionar:

```js
// Valor que vem do multi-select:
var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

// Cria uma lista de objetos:
var result = [];

values.forEach(function(value) {
  result.push({id: value});
}); 

// Converte o objeto para JSON:
var json = JSON.stringify(result);

// Exibe o resultado em JSON:
console.log(json);
```

O seu resultado será uma lista de objetos:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"}]
```

---

Uma alternativa é criar apenas um objeto e definir a lista de `id` como seu valor:

```js
// Valor que vem do multi-select:
var values = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

// Cria um objeto de índice "id" e valores "value":
var result = {id: values};

// Converte o objeto para JSON:
var json = JSON.stringify(result);

// Exibe o resultado em JSON:
console.log(json);
```

O resultado, nesta forma, será:

```
{"id":["1","2","3","4","5"]}
```

Que ao meu ver faria mais sentido, mas depende da sua aplicação.

Comment: não está funcionando a primeira forma.. nessa segunda forma, dará para fazer um laço for no php? para pegar esses valores de um por um?

Comment: Sim, dá. Como você tentou fazer?

Comment: Ainda estou tendo exibir no console.log, mas percebi que meu valor está vindo como objeto e não como string

Comment: Essa informação não ajudou em muita coisa. O que você quer fazer, o que você fez e por quê não deu certo? Qual foi o erro?

Comment: Dá certo quando eu envio direto uma string para converter em vetor, mas percebi que valor que estou recebendo é um objeto, então o split já não funciona, mas estou tentando ai te informo

Comment: Mas você havia informado que era uma string: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204125/converter-string-em-json/204160?noredirect=1#comment418157_204150

Comment: isso, ao meu ver eu pensei que era uma string, mas eu dei o comando typeof valor e ele me informou que é um objeto, eu errei mesmo

Comment: Então verifique aí como está de fato e edite sua pergunta para que fique da forma correta. Após isso eu edito a resposta de acordo com a pergunta.

Comment: Pronto! Editei. Mas consegui obter o resultado da segunda maneira que você sugeriu. Muito obrigado! Só que saiu assi: `Object {id: "["2","3"]"}` tem algum problema?

Comment: Pelo exemplo que você colocou no JSFiddle, você já recebe o valor como um *array*, então a solução da Aline deveria funcionar. Você deve ter feito algo errado.

Comment: Poxa era isso mesmo o que você falou. Ja vinha como array, mas eu pensava que o só o fato de ver lá era uma string. Mancada minha. As suas duas opções resolvem.. Desculpa ai. E muito obrigado, mais uma vez

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você tenha um array de inteiros então:

```
var lValoresDoSelect = [1,2,3,4,5];

var lIds = new Array();
$.each(lValoresDoSelect, function(index, obj){
   lIds.push({ id: obj });
});
```

Supondo que você vá obter essas informações de um elemento:

```
var lIds = new Array();
    $.each($(".multiselect:selected"), function(index, obj){
       lIds.push({ id: $(obj).text() });
    });
```

Comment: Oi Aline, duas coisas que talvez seria interessante adicionar a sua resposta: (1) Explicar o porquê de você ter criado um arranjo de objetos ao invés de apenas um objeto (no caso, porque a chave `id` se repete e não seria possível em apenas um, por isso o arranjo) e (2) Comentar como é feito a converção de um arranjo do JavaScript para JSON, utilizando a função `JSON.stringify`, visto que este é o objetivo principal da pergunta.

Comment: o valor não vem em vetor, ele vem em string